# How to get the final status after executing multiple AsyncTasks

Tags: android, android-asynctask, widget

I have implemented a widget that uses collections view (AdapterViewFlipper). This widget downloads average 10 - 20 images and displays them on it. It is calling 'notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged' whenever it downloads an image. But because of this implementation, it is flickering 10 - 20 times. Is there any way to avoid this? I have thought about displaying a loading icon until it finishes all the image downloadings, but I have no idea how the widget receives a notification all image downloading processes are completed.

For example, if there are 10 images to be downloaded and it is executed using 10 AsyncTask objects. How can the widget determine if all download processes are completed (regardless all of them are successfully downloaded or some of them are failed)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that in the case of downloading images, you can refer to the downloaded images at any time, You could maintain a counter. Increment the counter in onPreExecute and decrement it in onPostExecute of the Asynctasks. If the counter reaches 0, call the notify method.

Comment: But there will be multiple asyncTask objects. How can the widget manage a single counter for all objects unless it stores in a file? I am afraid that storing it in a file as there will be rapid IO processes that might conflict each other